# Angular ui.router resolve not working when ng-controller put in html view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following nested states for the ui-router

index.html

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
<body>
```

view.homepage.html

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="controllerHome">
  <div id="middle">
    <div ui-view>
     <input type="text" ng-model="check">
     <button ng-click="test()">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div
</div>
```

Here is my state definition js file

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp',['ui.router']);

testApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.
        otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home',
            {
                url:'/',
                templateUrl : './templates/view.homepage.html',
                controller : 'controllerHome',
                resolve : {
                    userSession : function($http){
                     return $http({
                            method : "POST",
                            url : '/getSession'
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
})
```

homeController.js

```
testApp.controller('controllerHome',function($scope,$http,userSession){

    $scope.check = "";
    $scope.test = function(){
      console.log($scope.check);
    }

})
```

When I put the resolve I in the state definition I get the following error Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider.

So I tried removing the ng-controller directive but when I remove the ng-controller directive from the view, the value of $scope.check in the controllerHome is blank after click on the button.

I want to remove the ng-controller directive from the html view and put the resolve in the state definition.

Comment: Don't add child elements to ui-view

<div id="header" ng-controller="controllerHome">
  <div id="middle">
    <div ui-view></div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="check">
     <button ng-click="test()">Click</button>
  </div
</div>

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/hellogalaxy#resolve), Resolve property in UI-Router works that way.

The properties that are in resolve will be retrieved before activating that state.

> resolve: block is an object on a state definition. Each key is the
>   name of some data to load, and each value is a function which returns
>   a promise for the data. Resolve functions are injected using Angular’s
>   injector.

By the properties you have in the resolve, those properties and corresponding functions are resolved and the promises are injected into controller of the state.

So it is **mandatory** to have a controller name in the state instead of having it in the HTML as **`ng-controller`**.

An the problem that you are facing is to be solved using a factory **sessionService** which has the session Details and return them by calling a method in that service.

Have a look at the below

1. Your config must contain the state as below

   ```
   .state('home',
       {
           url:'/',
           templateUrl : './templates/view.homepage.html',
           controller : 'controllerHome',
           resolve : {
               userSession : function(sessionService){
                  return : sessionService.getUserSession();
               }
           }
   ```
2. Create a factory with the name sessionService as below

   ```
   testApp.factory('sessionService', function() {
       var getUserSession= function(){
               $http({
                       method : "POST",
                       url : '/getSession'
               });
       }
       return {
               getUserSession:getUserSession
       }
   });
   ```
3. Try displaying your session value in the console in your controller
   which can be modified as

   ```
   testApp.controller('controllerHome',function($scope,$http,userSession){

       $scope.check = "";
       console.log(userSession);
       $scope.test = function(){
         console.log($scope.check);
       }
   })
   ```